# What is the latest state-of-art in designing CSS based forms?

Tags: html, css

I have a few years experience in designing web applications but up until this point, to design a form in CSS, I open up a text editor and start writing code. This works for me but is ending up taking a lot of time if I have to design bigger forms (like say, wizards). So a question for all the gurus around here: What is the fastest way to design CSS based forms that look decent enough?

PS: I am not looking for completely automated ways. I am only looking for something that is able to produce readable CSS code that I can dig into and play further.

Answer (score 1):

I know you said you were not looking for completely automated ways, but if you're looking to build forms quickly without writing a lot of code you might want to check out one of these online form builder's - you can tweak the final mark-up that gets produced.

- [Wufoo](http://wufoo.com/)
- [Form Stack](http://www.formstack.com/)

In terms of just building your own forms from scratch: I would recommend wrapping your form inputs in other elements you can use to create nice alignment of field and label. I like to put my form inputs inside a definition list, that way each label can be a <dt> and each input canbe wrapped in a <dd> - then the dt can be float left making for a nice alignment.

Also worth considering if you don't need to focus on older browsers are [all the cool things you can add to forms thanks to HTML5 and CSS3](http://24ways.org/2009/have-a-field-day-with-html5-forms).

Answer (score 0):

The 960 Grid System seems to be pretty popular lately for css based layout. 
http://960.gs/

This is one of the better tutorials I've seen on the subject: http://sixrevisions.com/web_design/the-960-grid-system-made-easy/

It has decents semantics around the class names and is documented so your teammates can learn on their own, or maybe already know it.

Comment: What does the "960 Grid System" have to do with designing forms other than aligning the elements? And pixel-based fixed width layouts? Why can't designers embrace the flexibility of CSS instead of limiting themselves to the constraints of something like this?

Comment: Calm down killer. No one said anybody had to use anything.

Comment: I agree with you RoToRa. There is a certain trend that we currently can see. Users are viewing websites with other media than computers like iOS devices (iPhone, iPod Touch, iPad), Android devices, Windows Mobile 7 devices and even on TVs. The 960 Grid System is not very relevant for these devices.

Comment: Everything is dependent on the context in which it is used. I am all for coding my own css, but one thing I can assure you is that a framework adds a lot of value in keeping a team of developers using consistent semantics within their code. In addition to the fact that you can leverage existing knowledge, and hire a new employee that maybe knows the framework already. There is no silver bullet, and the 960 Grid System wasn't suggested as a solution for mobile devices. It is however an easy way to construct a grid based form layout, since every form I've ever seen is laid out like a grid.

Comment: After reading my answer again, I believe even more firmly it addresses the questions of both "CSS based forms" and "readable css code".